# Wpf and EntityFramework

Tags: wpf, entity-framework

I'm using WPF with entityFramework.
I want the EF's generated objects to notify when property changed.

Should I enter to the generated code and implement the INotifyPropertyChanged?
maybe with partial class ?!

what's the best practice when EF is in the picture ?

Answer (score 1):

Since EF4 supports now different code generation strategies, I would remove the default one and use ADO.NET Self tracking entity generator instead. This gives you the ability to modify HOW the entities get generated by the framework (using T4 template)...also entities generated by this implement INPC interface.